# Sass check if a rule is applied to a class

Tags: css, if-statement, sass, border-box

I have a class that should use one rule if a particular style is already applied and another if a different style is already applied. For example, say someone includes my stylesheet and has `box-sizing` set to `border-box`, how can I check whether my class will get such a rule applied?

```
// from another person's stylesheet
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

// rules created by my Sass mixin
.triangle {
    // if `border-box` xyz, else abc
}
```

Comment: I'm a SASS newbie too, maybe look into SASS functions. Get reading the [basic guide](http://sass-lang.com/guide), then move onto [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html). SCSS > SASS for me too :)

Comment: I already took a look at the basic guide. I am looking for a modernizr style rule detection mechanism, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with CSS or SASS.

Notice that this is not a trivial problem: The ordering of your CSS determines the applied css properties (you can overwrite css properties). You can constraint CSS properties to your wildest html paths, which the SASS compiler does not even know of, since it is independent of the html code. Both would make your desired functionality hard to implement.

Actually I also cannot think of a use case for that functionality. Maybe you can solve your problem by using more and more semantic css classes on your html elements. As a starting point for reading you might want to read chapters 3, 6 and 7 of [Scalable and Modular Architecture for CSS](http://smacss.com/).

Comment: The use case is I'm making a library and everything needs to work whether or not border-box is applied for any/all parts of the project. I need to account for that with different rules, so I need to know when to apply which rule. For some things, there isn't a one size fits all solution, and I can't make people pick.

Comment: If you don't even know all of the applied CSS on compile time (which would be the case, if you compile your SASS and ship only CSS code), there is surely no way you can achieve your desired result. CSS does not provide this functionality. Maybe you can ship some little javascript, which adds class attributes based on css properties, which you then can use to apply different CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with CSS because CSS is a declarative language. Sass doesn't change the way CSS works; it just makes it easier to write CSS.

If you're not sure whether the declaration will be there, just declare it.

Example:

```
// from another person's stylesheet
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

// rules created by my Sass mixin
.triangle {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border solid red 15px;
}
```

Or if you want to use standard `box-sizing`:

```
// rules created by my Sass mixin
.triangle {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border solid blue 15px;
}
```

This is fairly standard use of CSS's cascade.